# How to pass a variable from JS to html <object data=> and <embed src=>

Tags: javascript, html

I have been looking for this for hours, really could not find any good information on this.
Do not know if is even possible.

```
<script>
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var referencia=urlParams.get('parameter');
    var link1="https://www.example.com";
    if (referencia==null){
      referencia="CLS";
    }
    link1=link1+"?refer="+referencia;
</script>

<div>
   <object data="link1 goes here">
         <embed src="link1 goes here"> </embed>
   </object>
</div>
```

I did saw some solutions using IDs and then use document.getElementById('ID').src = link1, same for .data=link1, but does not work.

Any help will appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Whats you expected output please ?

Comment: Is a page that has embed on it a page that has a form, all works but I need to pass that extra variable on the link. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<div>
   <object id="objectID" data="">
         <embed id="embedID" src=""> </embed>
   </object>
</div>

<script>
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var referencia = urlParams.get('parameter');
    var link1 = "https://www.example.com";

    if (referencia==null){
      referencia="CLS";
    }
    
    link1 = link1 + "?refer=" + referencia;

    document.getElementById("objectID").setAttribute("data", link1);
    document.getElementById("embedID").setAttribute("data", link1);
</script>
```

Remember putting your javascript code after the HTML code. If you need to put some javascript before your HTML, make sure and check that the document is ready before trying to access to the element via getElementById.

Comment: You shouldn't need an `id` on both of the elements. Put the ID on the outer "object" element and `const outer = document.getElementById('objectID')` then get the inner "embed" by `const embed = outer.querySelector('embed')` (oh, and learn to use `const` and `let` instead of using `var`)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much works perfect, living and learning. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @c.almeida Please mark this answer as a solution by click the tick mark on this answer so that this question is considered as resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Ricdizio code worked on first try only change I had to make  was the embedID one was to atritibute src not data.
document.getElementById("embedID").setAttribute("scr", link1);

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add an `id` to both elements, as shown below.

```
<object id="id-1">
  <iframe id="id-2"></iframe>
</object>
```

Now you can link to those elements.

```js
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var referencia=urlParams.get('parameter');
var link1="https://www.example.com";
if (referencia==null){
  referencia="CLS";
}
link1+="?refer="+referencia;

document.getElementById("id-1").setAttribute("data", link1);
document.getElementById("id-2").setAttribute("src", link1);
```

```html
<div>
   <object id="id-1">
         <iframe id="id-2"></iframe>
   </object>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need an `id` on both elements, see my comment on ricdizio's answer. — in fact, how is this different than ricdizio's answer? Seems like an exact copy to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
 document.getElementByID('id');
```

or you can use

```
document.querySelector('#id);
```

to change the information.

example:

```js
const embedEl = document.querySelector('#embed');
    
    const link = "https://foo.foo";

    embedEl.setAttribute('src', link);
```

```html
   <embed src="" id="embed"><embed>
```

in your html you'll need to add an ID property to your embed tag.

```
<embed src="" id="embed"><embed>
```

If you would like some further reading, I highly recommend:
https://www.theodinproject.com